# Как правильно поместить интерфейс в префаб Unity

Tags: unity3d, интерфейс, prefabs

Я никогда раньше не делал игру с множеством уровней в Unity и столкнулся с непониманием как реализовать правильную работу интерфейса для такой игры. Как можно поместить интерфейс в префаб или префабы так, чтобы можно было загрузить его на любом уровне игры. Когда я пытался запихнуть интерфейс в один префаб, Unity вылетала при запуске сцены. Когда я разделил их на несколько префабов стало всё работать, но теперь не понятно как привязать к интерфейсу UIManeger, который необходим для его работы [image: Так выглядит интерфейс в моей игре для каждого уровня]

Comment: Создавать новую сцену для каждого отдельно уровня плохая практика. Попробуйте поместить объекты уровня в префаб и уже их подгружать